# porqué tkinter no me deja colocar el button en el labelframe?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

hola soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación estoy creando un programa de ventas, con python 3 y tkinter. Estoy tratando de hacer un sistema de navegación de paginas para dicho programa con funciones, destruyendo los frames con destroy() y volviendo a llamar las funciones para cambiar el contenido de la pagina. El problema es cuando colocó el frame en root, el labelframe en frame ya no puedo colocar nada en labelframe, el botón aparece en frame y no en labelframe.

Espero que me puedan ayudar gracias.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720") 
root.title('Punto de venta')

def des():

    frameI.destroy()

def ventanaI():

    global frameI
    frameI= Frame(root, width=1280, height=720, bg='blue')
    frameI.place(x=0, y=0)

    caja= LabelFrame(frameI, text='Iniciar sesion', width=400, height=300).place(x=440, y=210)

    bt1=Button(caja, text='Entrar' command=des).place(x=0, y=0) 

ventanaI()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Que error te sale??

Comment: el botón no aparece dentro del labelframe y cuando destruyo el frame también desaparece el boton, por lógica el botón esta en el frame a pesar de que indique la ubicación en labelframe. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, te falta indentar la llamada de la función ventanaI, tambien si quieres llamar el `LabelFrame`, tienes que primero lamarlo en la venta root.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720") 
root.title('Punto de venta')
FrameI = Notebook(root)

def des():

    frameI.destroy()

def ventanaI():

    global frameI
    frameI= Frame(root, width=1280, height=720, bg='blue')
    frameI.place(x=0, y=0)

    caja= LabelFrame(frameI, text='Iniciar sesion', width=400, height=300).place(x=440, y=210)

    bt1=Button(caja, text='Entrar' command=des).place(x=0, y=0) 

    ventanaI()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta empaquetar el LabelFrame en una linea diferente y veras que sale

```
caja= LabelFrame(frameI, text='Iniciar sesion', width=400, height=300)
caja.place(x=440, y=210)
```